# Getting an error during the deploying webapplication "Could not open Source file: Could not find a part of the path"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, umbraco, web-deployment, umbraco7

I got an error during the deploying my web-application.
The title of error is `Could not open Source file: Could not find a part of the path`

> 'Could not open Source file: Could not find a part of the path 
>   'E:\ARCHIVES\Projects\Main\Jahan.Handicraft\Jahan.Handicraft.Web.Mvc.UmbracoCms.App\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir\App_Plugins\UmbracoForms\Data\Web.config;\App_Plugins\UmbracoForms\Data\Web.config'.'.

I've used `Umbraco 7.4.3` und `ASP.NET MVC` in my project.
I'd like deploy it on localhost.

How can I solve this problem?[image: picture of error]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Post installation**

You should note that the Umbraco nuget package adds a build step to always include the Umbraco folders when you deploy using Web One-Click Publish with Visual Studio.
You can see these folders in packages`/UmbracoCms x.y.z/build/UmbracoCms.targets`
Should you need to exclude any of these folders or content, you can add a target to your .pubxml files in the properties/Publish folder. For instance if you need to exclude json data a plugin generates during production.

```
<Target Name="StopUmbracoFromPublishingAppPlugins" AfterTargets="AddUmbracoFilesToOutput">
    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Remove=".\App_Plugins\UmbracoForms\Data\**\*.*"/>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Reference: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Install/install-umbraco-with-nuget#post-installation

Answer (score 6):

This is a failed attempt at transforming connection strings in sublevel configurations files.

To disable this transformation, edit the publish profile under `Properties\PublishProfiles` and set the value of the `AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings` element to `false`. Add the element if missing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- 
    ...
    Other settings
    ...
    -->
    <AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>false</AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I got it from this blog (which is not mine): http://blog.aabech.no/archive/web-deploy-says-could-not-open-source-file-some-webconfig-when-you-publish-an-umbraco-site/

Comment: I am not using Umbraco and I had this same error. This answer worked for me anyway, so I say it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I can confirm this works with Umbraco also